# What to put into an app about dialog?

Tags: android, release

I am about to release an Android app into the PlayStore.

Currently my about dialog says:

```
Application Name
Copyright © 2016
All rights reserved
Owned by My Name
myEmail@address

Used LGPL3 Library:
MapsForge Version 0.6.0

Used Icons from:
https://icons8.com
```

Is that sufficient or are there more things I have to put in there? BTW I am using OpenStreetMap Data. Do I have to refer to them?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put anything at all into your Help/About dialog, nor are you compelled to put specific things in there by any external authority.  What you put into the Help/About dialog is entirely up to you.

It does provide a handy place for certain things, however:

- The name of the program
- A copyright statement
- A "terms of use" statement
- Author credits
- Attributions
- Licensing obligations

You can put any, all, or none of these things into the Help/About dialog, depending on your specific needs.

Comment: But I read that I have for instance attribute the free icons I use and refer to the website I got them from. If I do not attribute in the About dialog, then where else?

Comment: A readme file, perhaps?  Or a splash screen?  There isn't anything in those free icons websites that says you must put that in the Help/About dialog, though that would be a logical and convenient place to put it.

Comment: Ok. Then I should have probably spelled my question like this: *I do not provide anythink else than an about dialog. What do I have to put in there?* :)

Comment: You don't have to put anything at all there, unless you have a requirements document, a supervisor, stakeholder or other legitimate authority that specifically states you have to put something there.

Answer (score 1):

The about-box requirements may depend on requirements of the libs/dataservices and other resources you use. i.e. for openstreetmap see http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright.

If you put app version info into the about box (i.e. MyApp version 1.2.3) you may make technical support easier because a customer can tell you with wich app version your app crashed